# RailsTutorial/require test_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've been following the RailsTutorial.org book (I'm at Ch. 6) and had no problem making a page appear on 'localhost:3000', was able to edit the html.erb files and css to my heart's content...then suddenly, I receive an error in terminal:

> ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method   `test_helper' for main:Object):app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:1:in`'

As well as a, "We're sorry, but something went wrong." on localhost.

[Here is my github push...](https://github.com/defhand/sample_app)

What can I do to get this back up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `require test_helper` from the file **app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb**. That line should only be into your tests since it is a helper designed for tests. And especially into the **tests/models/user_test.rb** file since you're on Chapter 6.

Comment: Thank you! I copied all the stuff from the static_pages_controller_test.rb into the controller on accident at some point, just had to switch all that back and we're in business.